# Filter pane in SharePoint modern page

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, web-part, modern-experience, sitepages

I have a SharePoint list which I am showing on a page.

I have to add filter/search functionality for list web part since items in list will grow to up to 800.

So I am looking for user friendly way to do this. Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

Create a list view:

[Create, change, or delete a view of a list or library](https://support.microsoft.com/office/create-change-or-delete-a-view-of-a-list-or-library-27ae65b8-bc5b-4949-b29b-4ee87144a9c9)

Then configure the list view web part to use that the list view (that contains your filter):

[Use the List web part](https://support.microsoft.com/office/use-the-list-web-part-ef0a1b80-f8b3-443d-b04a-1e76c70b5537)

Comment: Thanks Callum, i am looking for option, where i donot have to use filters from list web part but add filter panel on left side of page which checkboxes/dropdowns so filter out side of list web part in essence. any idea what is possible? because i have gallery view not table view on page